# converting string containing dictionary into a list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

variable `a` contains a list of dictionaries but its type is of string.

```
a
```

output:`"[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]"`

```
a[0]
```

output:`'['`

I want to convert `a` into a list so that I can access the dictionary using index

Comment: Try not to get into this situation in the first place; use the `json` module to produce serialisations of such objects instead of using `str()` on a list to store it in a file or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ast package.

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval(your_str)
```